# How to identify approximately (threshold defined) continuous non null data using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, time-series

I would like to extract rainfall events from a rainfall time serie while allowing X dry hours (as a parameter) inside the same event. So, by rainfall event, I mean approximately continuous rainfall (RF > 0) with maximum X consecutive dry hours (RF = 0) inside.

I actually don't want to do it the hard way with iterators and increments and I look for pandas or numpy/scipy tools that can be a relief.

Here is a sample of my dataframe. `RF` is raw rainfall and `RFfill` is RF.interpolate() to fill nodata. `evtId`is field created to store events unique id's.

```
                    TS   RF  RFfill  evtId
0  1997-11-27 14:00:00  0.3     0.3    NaN
1  1997-11-27 15:00:00  1.1     1.1    NaN
2  1997-11-27 16:00:00  0.2     0.2    NaN
3  1997-11-27 17:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
4  1997-11-27 18:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
5  1997-11-27 19:00:00  1.1     1.1    NaN
6  1997-11-27 20:00:00  0.6     0.6    NaN
7  1997-11-27 21:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
8  1997-11-27 22:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
9  1997-11-27 23:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
10 1997-11-28 00:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
11 1997-11-28 01:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
12 1997-11-28 02:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
13 1997-11-28 03:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
14 1997-11-28 04:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
15 1997-11-28 05:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
16 1997-11-28 06:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
17 1997-11-28 07:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
18 1997-11-28 08:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
19 1997-11-28 09:00:00  0.8     0.8    NaN
20 1997-11-28 10:00:00  1.1     1.1    NaN
21 1997-11-28 11:00:00  2.3     2.3    NaN
22 1997-11-28 12:00:00  1.4     1.4    NaN
23 1997-11-28 13:00:00  0.4     0.4    NaN
24 1997-11-28 14:00:00  0.2     0.2    NaN
25 1997-11-28 15:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
26 1997-11-28 16:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
27 1997-11-28 17:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
28 1997-11-28 18:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
29 1997-11-28 19:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
30 1997-11-28 20:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
```

Here is the expected output with 5 hours of allowed dry hours :

```
                    TS   RF  RFfill  evtId
0  1997-11-27 14:00:00  0.3     0.3    0
1  1997-11-27 15:00:00  1.1     1.1    0
2  1997-11-27 16:00:00  0.2     0.2    0
3  1997-11-27 17:00:00  0.0     0.0    0
4  1997-11-27 18:00:00  0.0     0.0    0
5  1997-11-27 19:00:00  1.1     1.1    0
6  1997-11-27 20:00:00  0.6     0.6    0
7  1997-11-27 21:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
8  1997-11-27 22:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
9  1997-11-27 23:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
10 1997-11-28 00:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
11 1997-11-28 01:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
12 1997-11-28 02:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
13 1997-11-28 03:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
14 1997-11-28 04:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
15 1997-11-28 05:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
16 1997-11-28 06:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
17 1997-11-28 07:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
18 1997-11-28 08:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
19 1997-11-28 09:00:00  0.8     0.8    1
20 1997-11-28 10:00:00  1.1     1.1    1
21 1997-11-28 11:00:00  2.3     2.3    1
22 1997-11-28 12:00:00  1.4     1.4    1
23 1997-11-28 13:00:00  0.4     0.4    1
24 1997-11-28 14:00:00  0.2     0.2    1
25 1997-11-28 15:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
26 1997-11-28 16:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
27 1997-11-28 17:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
28 1997-11-28 18:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
29 1997-11-28 19:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
30 1997-11-28 20:00:00  0.0     0.0    NaN
```

Any ideas that could help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

df = pd.DataFrame({'RF': [ 0.3,  1.1,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  
                           1.1,  0.6,  0. , 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  
                           0.8,  1.1,  2.3,  1.4,  0.4,  0.2, 0. ,  0. ,  
                           0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]})

consecutive = 5
mask = df['RF'] > 0
df['mask'] = mask
df['dilation'] = ndimage.binary_dilation(mask, structure=[1]*(consecutive+1))
df['erosion'] = ndimage.binary_erosion(df['dilation'], 
    structure=[1]*(consecutive+1), border_value=1)
df['labeled'], nobjs = ndimage.label(df['erosion'])
df['evtId'] = np.where(df['labeled'] > 0, df['labeled']-1, np.nan)
print(df[['RF', 'evtId']])
```

yields

```
#      RF  evtId
# 0   0.3      0
# 1   1.1      0
# 2   0.2      0
# 3   0.0      0
# 4   0.0      0
# 5   0.0      0
# 6   0.0      0
# 7   0.0      0
# 8   1.1      0
# 9   0.6      0
# 10  0.0    NaN
# 11  0.0    NaN
# 12  0.0    NaN
# 13  0.0    NaN
# 14  0.0    NaN
# 15  0.0    NaN
# 16  0.8      1
# 17  1.1      1
# 18  2.3      1
# 19  1.4      1
# 20  0.4      1
# 21  0.2      1
# 22  0.0    NaN
# 23  0.0    NaN
# 24  0.0    NaN
# 25  0.0    NaN
# 26  0.0    NaN
# 27  0.0    NaN
```

---

**Explanation**: First prepare a binary mask which is True where `df['RF'] > 0`:

```
mask = (df['RF'] > 0)
df['mask'] = mask
#      RF   mask
# 0   0.3   True
# 1   1.1   True
# 2   0.2   True
# 3   0.0  False
# 4   0.0  False
# 5   0.0  False
# 6   0.0  False
# 7   0.0  False
# 8   1.1   True
# 9   0.6   True
# ...
```

Next, [dilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29) the mask to join together islands of `True`s (rainy days) separated by 5 or fewer `False`s (non-rainy days):

```
df['dilation'] = ndimage.binary_dilation(mask, structure=[1]*(consecutive+1))
#      RF   mask dilation
# 0   0.3   True     True
# 1   1.1   True     True
# 2   0.2   True     True
# 3   0.0  False     True   <--, 
# 4   0.0  False     True      |
# 5   0.0  False     True      |  dilation filled over 5 rainy days
# 6   0.0  False     True      |
# 7   0.0  False     True   <--'
# 8   1.1   True     True
# 9   0.6   True     True
# 10  0.0  False     True   <-- But the `True`s extend a bit too far
# 11  0.0  False     True   <--
# 12  0.0  False    False
# 13  0.0  False     True
# 14  0.0  False     True
# 15  0.0  False     True
# 16  0.8   True     True
# 17  1.1   True     True
# 18  2.3   True     True
# 19  1.4   True     True
# 20  0.4   True     True
# 21  0.2   True     True
# 22  0.0  False     True
# 23  0.0  False     True
# 24  0.0  False    False
# 25  0.0  False    False
# 26  0.0  False    False
# 27  0.0  False    False
```

Next use [binary erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) to remove the `True`s that have extended too far.

```
df['erosion'] = ndimage.binary_erosion(df['dilation'], structure=[1]*(consecutive+1), 
                                       border_value=1)
#      RF   mask dilation erosion
# 0   0.3   True     True    True
# 1   1.1   True     True    True
# 2   0.2   True     True    True
# 3   0.0  False     True    True
# 4   0.0  False     True    True
# 5   0.0  False     True    True
# 6   0.0  False     True    True
# 7   0.0  False     True    True
# 8   1.1   True     True    True
# 9   0.6   True     True    True
# 10  0.0  False     True   False  <--,
# 11  0.0  False     True   False     |
# 12  0.0  False    False   False     | The Falses have been expanded
# 13  0.0  False     True   False     | (The Trues eroded)
# 14  0.0  False     True   False     |
# 15  0.0  False     True   False  <--'
# 16  0.8   True     True    True
# 17  1.1   True     True    True
# 18  2.3   True     True    True
# 19  1.4   True     True    True
# 20  0.4   True     True    True
# 21  0.2   True     True    True
# 22  0.0  False     True   False
# 23  0.0  False     True   False
# 24  0.0  False    False   False
# 25  0.0  False    False   False
# 26  0.0  False    False   False
# 27  0.0  False    False   False
```

Now that the `True`s represent "rainfall events", we can assign a unique number to each rainfall event by using [`ndimage.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html):

```
df['labeled'], nobjs = ndimage.label(df['erosion'])
#      RF   mask dilation erosion  labeled
# 0   0.3   True     True    True        1
# 1   1.1   True     True    True        1
# 2   0.2   True     True    True        1
# 3   0.0  False     True    True        1
# 4   0.0  False     True    True        1
# 5   0.0  False     True    True        1
# 6   0.0  False     True    True        1
# 7   0.0  False     True    True        1
# 8   1.1   True     True    True        1
# 9   0.6   True     True    True        1
# 10  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 11  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 12  0.0  False    False   False        0
# 13  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 14  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 15  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 16  0.8   True     True    True        2
# 17  1.1   True     True    True        2
# 18  2.3   True     True    True        2
# 19  1.4   True     True    True        2
# 20  0.4   True     True    True        2
# 21  0.2   True     True    True        2
# 22  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 23  0.0  False     True   False        0
# 24  0.0  False    False   False        0
# 25  0.0  False    False   False        0
# 26  0.0  False    False   False        0
# 27  0.0  False    False   False        0
```

and use `np.where` to reduce the label number by one when `df['labeled'] > 0`, and assign `np.nan` otherwise:

```
df['evtId'] = np.where(df['labeled'] > 0, df['labeled']-1, np.nan)
#      RF   mask dilation erosion  labeled  evtId
# 0   0.3   True     True    True        1      0
# 1   1.1   True     True    True        1      0
# 2   0.2   True     True    True        1      0
# 3   0.0  False     True    True        1      0
# 4   0.0  False     True    True        1      0
# 5   0.0  False     True    True        1      0
# 6   0.0  False     True    True        1      0
# 7   0.0  False     True    True        1      0
# 8   1.1   True     True    True        1      0
# 9   0.6   True     True    True        1      0
# 10  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 11  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 12  0.0  False    False   False        0    NaN
# 13  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 14  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 15  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 16  0.8   True     True    True        2      1
# 17  1.1   True     True    True        2      1
# 18  2.3   True     True    True        2      1
# 19  1.4   True     True    True        2      1
# 20  0.4   True     True    True        2      1
# 21  0.2   True     True    True        2      1
# 22  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 23  0.0  False     True   False        0    NaN
# 24  0.0  False    False   False        0    NaN
# 25  0.0  False    False   False        0    NaN
# 26  0.0  False    False   False        0    NaN
# 27  0.0  False    False   False        0    NaN
```

---

Note that a dilation followed by an erosion is called a
[closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_%28morphology%29).  The reason
why I used `ndimage.binary_dilation` and `ndimage.binary_erosion` instead of
just calling `ndimage.binary_closing` is because I needed to set
`border_value=1` to prevent the border edges from getting eroded. Compare `df['erosion']` with

```
ndimage.binary_closing(mask, structure=[1]*(consecutive+1))
```

and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thank you, I have learnt a lot today about dilation and erosion. I was trying to do something similar with `ndimage.filters.generic_filter()` with a footprint of `np.ones(consecutive)` and playing with `np.trim_zeros()` but it was a bit far-fetched.